# Postgres - Query that Join two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two table that need to join them in one table.

1: First Query

```
SELECT cu.user_name,
       li.successdate
FROM logininfo li
JOIN user_mapping um ON um.user_key = li.username
JOIN cwd_user cu ON um.username = cu.user_name
ORDER BY successdate;
```

Result:

```
      user_name      |       successdate
---------------------+-------------------------
 K_Daniel           | 2018-09-02 13:38:22.331
```

2:  Second Query

```
WITH last_login_date AS
(SELECT user_id
      , to_timestamp(CAST(cua.attribute_value AS double precision)/1000) AS last_login
   FROM cwd_user_attribute cua
  WHERE cua.attribute_name = 'lastAuthenticated'
    AND to_timestamp(CAST(cua.attribute_value AS double precision)/1000) < (CURRENT_DATE))
SELECT c.user_name
     , g.group_name
  FROM cwd_user c
 INNER JOIN last_login_date l ON (c.id = l.user_id)
 INNER JOIN cwd_membership m  ON (c.id = m.child_user_id)
 INNER JOIN cwd_group g       ON (m.parent_id = g.id)
 WHERE g.group_name LIKE '%CEO-%' ;
```

Result:

```
    user_name     |                     group_name
------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 K_Daniel        | CEO-Building1
```

3-Here is the expected result:

```
      user_name      |       successdate       |        group_name
---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------
     K_Daniel        | 2018-09-02 13:38:22.331 |       CEO-Building1
```

what is the appropriate query to join these table?

Any idea

Thanks,

Comment: You should add your sample data.

Comment: under result section I've put sample, I have two table like this

`table 1 
user_name      |       successdate
 K_Daniel           | 2018-09-02 13:38:22.331 `

`table 2
user_name  | group_name
 K_Daniel  | CEO-Building1`

Comment: You should add it in your question, not here,

Comment: it is exist on the post, under result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after serval workaround I found solution.

```
WITH last_login_date AS
(SELECT user_id
      , to_timestamp(CAST(cua.attribute_value AS double precision)/1000) AS last_login
   FROM cwd_user_attribute cua
  WHERE cua.attribute_name = 'lastAuthenticated'
    AND to_timestamp(CAST(cua.attribute_value AS double precision)/1000) < (CURRENT_DATE))
SELECT c.user_name
     , li.successdate
     , g.group_name
  FROM cwd_user c
 INNER JOIN last_login_date l ON (c.id = l.user_id)
 INNER JOIN cwd_membership m  ON (c.id = m.child_user_id)
 INNER JOIN cwd_group g       ON (m.parent_id = g.id)
 INNER JOIN user_mapping um ON (c.user_name = um.username)
 INNER JOIN logininfo li ON (um.user_key = li.username)
 WHERE g.group_name LIKE 'CEO-%' ;
```